# butterfly network in sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sorting-network

I am studying even odd merge sort in Robert Sedwick Algorithms in C++.

As part of the text author mentioned about how odd-even merge sort can be used to implement parallel sorting in sorting network. In this context author mentioned butterfly network

My question is what is basically butterfly network and why is it called butterfly. Explanation with simple example will be appreciated.

I have googled it but not find simple explanation with example.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter. There is a diagram of a butterfly network.

Comment: @PetarMinchev I am looking for what is butterfly network and why is it called so.

Comment: This website provides an example of butterfly network. http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html

Comment: This article is more focused on butterfly network sorting. http://www.actapress.com/PaperInfo.aspx?PaperID=455428&reason=500

Comment: The implementation of the non-recursive odd-even mergesort in the book is wrong. It generates redundant compare operations and misses others. See my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426337/how-to-fix-this-non-recursive-odd-even-merge-sort-algorithm) for details.

Answer (score 3):

A butterfly network is a certain kind of [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). A sorting network can be viewed as an abstract network (e.g. a data flow network) or quite concrete as an electric circuit.

Those networks consist of input and output wires, and a couple of comparator [multiplexers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) which route incoming values from one wire to another wire. It is an example of parallel sorting.

[image: Butterfly Network]

Source: [Universität Leipzig](http://stinfwww.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~mai03kbz/share/vorlesung/coco%20spezifikation/ParalleleAlgorithmen/Skript-ParAlg-1-2006.pdf)

In the above diagramm, the inputs are on the left set, the ouputs are on the right side,
the square boxes are comparators. The idea is that you can put arbitrary values from 0 to 15 at each input and they get routed to the ouputs by the comparators (which inspect the incoming value and decide to route to another wire or keep it on the same wire), all 0 values will be routed to the top output (000), all 1 values to the second output (001) etc.

The name is IMHO derived from the [butterfly graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram), which shows up for example in the [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm), this kind of data flow with it's crossing ressembles a butterfly.

[image: Butterfly Graph]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Butterfly-FFT.png)

If you look at the first diagram of the the butterfly network, you see it repeated over and over again.